# Как найти среднее арифметическое последовательности, если в ней есть знак "."

Tags: python, python-3.x, if, for, break

Задание:

Вычислите среднее арифметическое целых чисел и выведите его. Вы получите целые числа в отдельных строках. Числовая последовательность заканчивается точкой ".", поэтому прекратите считывать ввод на ней. Не округляйте результат до его вывода. На входе всегда будет хотя бы одно число.

Как мне найти ср. арифметическое, если "." - это str, а надо ведь, чтоб все int были?!

И ещё. Написано, что вывод последовательности должен быть в отдельных строках, а у меня список (list = []). И вывод в ряд получается. Я пробовала добавить `\n` , но не помогло. Может вообще без списка как-то надо?!

```
sequence = input()
list = []
for n in sequence:
    list.append(int(n)) 
    if n == ".":
        break
sum_list = sum(list)
len_list = len(list)
avg = sum_list / len_list
print(avg)
```

Comment: Есть пример ввода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Не называйте переменные именами объектов**, иначе питон будет путать (данные имена зарезервированны питоном)
2. Поменяйте местами последовательность строк в цикле, так как вы сначала добавляете, а потом проверяете, а должно быть наоборот:

Должно быть так:

```
if n == ".":
    break
lst.append(int(n))
```

3. > Написано, что вывод последовательности должен быть в отдельных строках, а у меня список (list = []). И вывод в ряд получается.

Не понял, что имеется ввиду, но думаю, данный пример поможет:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in lst:
    print(i)
```

Вывод:

```
1
2
3
4
```

4. В данной строчке `for i in sequence`, исходя из входных данных, происходит неправильная обработка, так как вы пытаетесь получить каждый символ в строке, что является неверным: `'5, 4, 10'` - > `5 , 4 , 1 0`(символы). Вам нужно разделить строку и при нахождении в некоторой разделенной строке точки, записать в список и закончить цикл.

Пример решения:

```
sequence = input()
lst = []
for n in sequence.split(', '):
    if '.' not in n:
        lst.append(int(n))
    else:
        lst.append(int(n.replace('.', '')))
        break
sum_list = sum(lst)
len_list = len(lst)
avg = sum_list / len_list
print(avg)
```

Вывод:

```
4.5
```

Comment: спасибо за напоминание об именах, есть за мной такой косяк...

Comment: стала тестировать систему на сайте. Там числа для ввода были: 5, 2, 10, 1. И вывод должен получиться 4,5 (что вполне логично), а моя программа почему-то выдала 5,0. Я даже не могу понять, как так могло получиться...

Comment: @Вика Мельникова ясно, я дополню ответ.

Comment: сама бы об replace я точно не додумалась, а про split вообще не знала))) Но это очень полезная информация!!! Благодарю за хорошие объяснения!!!

Comment: @ВикаМельникова не за что) впринципе, эти базовые моменты все есть в python-учебниках на доступном языке в интернете.